# A strange plant grew out of where my cilantro used to grow, can someone identify?

Tags: herbs, cilantro

When my cilantro withered (sad), I noticed a strange herbal stem grew out of the dirt, but I didn't pay much attention. Until recently, I noticed the plant flourishing and now it appears there is "fruit" thingies on its branches.

Could someone help me identify this please? Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a flowering stem off your cilantro - the little round things beneath the remains of the flowers are coriander seeds

http://www.vegetariantimes.com/blog/edible-gardening-101-harvesting-coriander-seeds/

You probably didn't notice the flowering stem arriving, and it would have contributed to the rest of the plant withering and dying back.

Comment: I see! Marvelous nature! Does that mean I could also plant these seeds at one point and they will grow into cilantros? I'm really new to indoor gardening, thank you for answering my question so quickly!

Comment: @benjaminz Yea - read the link, tells you how to harvest seeds both for eating and for saving to grow more plants.